# Is it possible to block just mobile traffic(Android/iPhone) & allow connections from Laptops on a WLAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, blocking, phone, browsing

Hardware: Dlink AP, Sonicwall,

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, it is possible to do by blacklisting the MAC addresses of mobile devices (problem is getting all of them).

But this is actually easily circumvented when you know what you are doing.